# Getting Count of Result Sets of SP (SP_MSForeachtable)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I was going to list all of the `Tables` in my DB which have no records.
As same as most of the times I used `SP_MSforeachtable` like:

```
EXEC sys.sp_MSforeachtable 'if (select Count(*) from ?) = 0 
                               select ''?'' ,Count(*) from ? '
```

And this gives me many result sets which I need to count them now.

[image: ![result sets pic]

---

I know there are other ways to work with tables but I was thinking 
 **getting count of sys.sp_MSforeachtable (or any SP) result sets**
might be usefull.

---

Also if there is way to **union all this result sets** I will appreciate to share.

Comment: You can query the `row_count` column in `sys.dm_db_partition_stats` DMV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query to extract the information you require

```
SELECT T.name, ST.row_count
FROM SYS.tables T
INNER JOIN SYS.dm_db_partition_stats ST ON T.object_id = ST.object_id
WHERE ST.row_count = 0
```